# Python - Bottle: Настройка роутинга; Подключение файлов

Tags: python, http

Есть небольшой статистический сайт, в 2-3 страницы. Перевел на `Python`. Теперь не понимаю как настроить роутинг, чтобы картинки, шрифты и т.п. подключались без проблем

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from bottle import route, run, template, static_file

@route('/')
def index():
    return static_file(filename='index.php', root='/var/www/domains/site.com/')

 @route('/foobar')
def index():
    return static_file(filename='index.php', root='/var/www/domains/site.com/foobar')



run(host='ip', port=4444)
```

в `html`, как обычно, указан путь для подключения файла, например:

```
<html>
    <body>
         <img src='http://site.com/img/img.jpg' />
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо! До меня дошло, что просто нужно роутировать каждый каталог с файлами:

```
@route('/img/<filename>')
def send_image(filename):
    return static_file(filename, root='/var/www/domains/site.com/img',)
```